# Insert blank line between date and hours for pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa " timeZone="#{applicationBean.timeZone}"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am looking to insert a line break between MM/dd/yyyy and hh:mm aa so that it shows up on the next line. Sadly I am unable to figure out a way to do it.

So have it be:
01/15/2015
10:15 AM

Here is the code:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa " timeZone="#{applicationBean.timeZone}" />
```

Comment: what is the problem. I dont understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<h:outputText value=#{bean.time} escape="false">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy '&lt;br/&gt;' hh:mm aa " timeZone="#{applicationBean.timeZone}" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I was wondering how to insert an HTML element.